# Need SQL-Server advice on how to make m2m relationships

Tags: sql-server, design-patterns, database-design

I have 4 tables: Company, Person, Job, Employee.

The first 3 tables need to have either one or two (no more no less) relationships to employee.

So my question is I should I do it, should I add two fields "Employee1" and "Employee2" to each of these tables marking one of them as nullable?

Or else?

I would like to hear from the **experts** before I am making my tables dirty.

Comment: How will the data be accessed? Or does this not matter, this is just an assignment on how to create a database?

Comment: I think that you would need to explain the "whys" of this situation.  As in, "Why would a Company record have one or two (and only one or two) Employees in it?"  IOW, what is the actual relationship of those employees to the Companies, Persons and Jobs?

Comment: @donkim: I am gonna access the DB by ADO.NET, but why would that matter?

Comment: @RBarryYoung: each c. p. j. needs to know which employee(s) is own it and is in charge on top of it.

Comment: @Shimmy: the proper way (I forget what it's called, it's been a while since I took my database class :) of doing this would be to have everything properly normalized. Depending on how your data is accessed, however, you'd want to optimize for frequent/expensive queries. For what it's worth, if you do go with the Employee1, Empoyee2 approach, make sure you have a constraint saying both can't be NULL. :)

Comment: @donkin, thank you for the NULL contraint advice, but I think about an easier way, I'll have the two fields one nullable as stated in my question, this will only leave the option for either ONE or TWO employees per record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't much choice when the table has to reference employees only one or two times.  Because you don't want to create this complex schema that that is going to create a nightmare of joins if all you need to support is one or two connections the the Employee table.

I would say go with your solution of adding Employee1 and Employee2.

Comment: except that in practice the need for Employee3 and 4 comes along....Do it right to begin with!

Comment: 1) It is a db design and modelling question. Joins are normal in databases.  Nothing to be scared of. The engine can handle it. 2) are you seriously advising a fixed no of Employees per Company ?!?

Comment: @Mitch, @PerformanceDBA, as I stated in my question, as per the customer, the company/person/job records will not need less than one or more than two employee relationships, the question is if to make each of these 3 tables dirty by adding 2 more fields to each on, or making my database dirty with adding 3 more CompanyEmployee, PersonEmployee, JobEmployee tables, so I would accept Nicks answer, unless there is going to be any other breakthru solution.

Comment: @Shimmy - One thing you will learn about software development is that the customer lies.  They may not think they do, but they do.  They will swear up and down that a certain condition cannot happen, then when you've written code based on their assertions, it turns out.. "Oh, except for this one thing" and now you have to rewrite all your code because it was based on invalid requirements.  When you can, don't design yourself into a corner if the customer changes their mind.

Comment: I know but this time I warned them that there won't be get back, they said OK. if they will now change it, I earn another salary, cuz I charge for time...